# Line_width not working in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I enabled wide_line feature in `VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures` and i am giving appropriate value in `pRasterizationState` as well. But i dont see the width increased for the lines. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the implementation support wide lines? Check the value of `VkphysicalDeviceFeatures:: wideLines` you get from `vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures`. Also check the `lineWidthRange` and `lineWidthGranularity` in `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits`.

Are you setting `VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_LINE_WIDTH` in `VkPipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo::pDynamicStates`? If so, you need to set the line width using `vkCmdSetLineWidth` rather than `VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo::lineWidth`.

Comment: When I querried number of physical devices using vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices it gave me 1. When I checked the properties available, it doesn't support wide lines. Strange.!

Comment: Out of curiosity, which GPU and OS is this?

Comment: Adreno 530 - G9350 with Android 7

Comment: I guess widelines features are not widely available in Android. Seems only  Tegra devices features it. Check [GPUinfo](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/)